# Actionscript 3 — Zoom in without messing up image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

I'm making a top-down game in flash, and I need to have the whole game zoomed in; the characters and scenery are really small. If I increase the height and width in flash, it messes up the image, putting pixels and strange coloration where they shouldn't be. What I am looking for is a way to change the size of the pixels, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll 'mess up' a bitmapped image by enlarging it beyond its resolution. Two easy solutions: 1. Make your characters and scenery as vector images.  Or 2. If you want them to be bitmaps (jpgs, png, whatever) create them initially at a size == the largest size you'll get to in your zoom. Then scale them down on stage to their starting scale. When you zoom in they'll look good.

Comment: Turning smoothing on will help (though not solve) if they scale above a `scaleX`/`scaleY` of 1 as well, though I definitely agree that it is best just not to scale beyond that point